# How to disable animation when switching workspace in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

When switching between workspaces in Win10 using, `ctrl+win <arrow-keys` is it possible to disable the animation for it?

Comment: You could do the opposite of this post [Virtual Desktops with No Transition animation](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/01de20d1-5250-43e1-ae21-7d808e8dc2dd/virtual-desktops-with-no-transition-animation?forum=win10itprogeneral)

Comment: @NetworkKingPin it is acceptable, but is there no way to disable the animation when switching workspace only?

Comment: I will have to get back to you on that when I get to my home setup there has to be a way.

Comment: Have a Look at this article go to Regedit and look at the options it may be the fading on custom. Play with them and let me know for sure have a look [Here](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/6377-visual-effects-settings-change-windows-10-a.html#option4)

Answer (score 81):

1. Click on the Start button (or push the Windows key on your keyboard)
2. Type "Adjust the appearance and performance of Windows" and select it from the suggestions menu.
3. Uncheck the checkbox for "Animate windows when minimizing and maximizing".

This will stop the animation when switching between Windows 10 Workspaces/Desktops.

Comment: This works. Any idea if it's possible to make the transition quicker for the touchpad selection as well?

Comment: It's a shame this isn't its own setting. They really are different classes of animation. I may switch between desktops hundreds of times a days and with two screens they both animate which literally makes me dizzy for about a second. But to disable it I need to also disable other window animations.

Comment: on windows 11, unchecking "Animate Controls and elements on Windows" did the trick