# Windows 10 disable animation when switching virtual desktops

Tags: windows, windows-10

How can I disable the animation when switching between virtual desktops (ctrl win left/right)? In the control panel ("adjust the appearance and performance of windows") I tried deselecting "Animate windows when minimising and maximising" but that disabled the minimise and maximise animation too.

How can I disable only the animation of switching virtual desktops? Thanks for your help, and sorry if this is a dumb question. I'm on Windows 10 version 20H2.

***Note: My previous question got marked as a duplicate of this one [View question](https://superuser.com/questions/1064931/how-to-disable-animation-when-switching-workspace-in-windows-10). However, this is not a duplicate. The answer in that question is precisely what I do not want to happen. I want to be able to disable ONLY the virtual desktop switching animation and NOT the minimise/maximise animation. The solution in the duplicate question disables all of those.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot disable virtual desktop animation individually. If you turned off the animation it will disable all animation also the desktop switching animation.

Answer (score 2):

Although it's been a while, so this may not help you, I found this solution that worked for me on Windows 11.

Press Win+X and select System.

Type "View advanced system settings"

On Advanced TAB click on settings under the performance row.

On Performance Options - Visual Effects, turn off you have "Animate controls and elements inside windows".

This should allow you to go through virtual desktops without the fade-in animation happening.

Comment: What was interesting to me, this affected animations inside browser. Fore example, animations on sites that used bootstrap components were gone.

Answer (score 1):

Update: The upgrade to Windows 11 removed the animation when switching virtual desktops. Not the solution I expected, but it works!